# ENOENT: no such file or directory .?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

This is error which am getting while post data and file.
I have followed 'academind' tutorial for building Restful API services, also i have been searching answer for this type of errors but nothing works for me.

Am using "multer" to upload file

The folder 'uploads' available in the folder but it shows

ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\project\uploads\2018-01-24T07:41:21.832Zcheck.jpg'"

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const productRoutes = require("./api/routes/products");

mongoose.connect('',
(err)=>{
    if(err){console.log(err)}
    else{console.log('DB Connected')}
})
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET");
    return res.status(200).json({});
  }
  next();
});

// Routes which should handle requests
app.use("/products", productRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new Error("Not found");
  error.status = 404;
  next(error);
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(error.status || 500);
  res.json({
    error: {
      message: error.message
    }
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

product.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads/');
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
  }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  // reject a file
  if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
  },
  fileFilter: fileFilter
});

router.post("/", checkAuth, upload.single('productImage'), (req, res, next) => {
  const product = new Product({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    name: req.body.name,
    price: req.body.price,
    productImage: req.file.path 
  });
  product
    .save()
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      res.status(201).json({
        message: "Created product successfully",
        createdProduct: {
            name: result.name,
            price: result.price,
            _id: result._id,
            request: {
                type: 'GET',
                url: "http://localhost:3000/products/" + result._id
            }
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: According to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx), colons (`:`) are not allowed in filenames. Try removing it (line 11 in `product.js`).

Answer (score 98):

**in product.js:**
After `new Date().toISOString()` add `replace()` to change **":"** to an accepted character.

Windows OS doesn't accept files with a **":"**

The person on Youtube is using MAC OS

E.g

`new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-')`

Comment: Thank you for this. Had the same issue and this solved it for me

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes.

Answer (score 24):

Try the following:

1. Require this as a constant (**const path = require('path');**)
2. Change this line

   cb(null, './uploads/');

With this:

```
cb(null, path.join(__dirname, '/uploads/'));
```

As I can see, you are trying to get a path that is not on served on the server, but rather a path that is on the server machine.

**UPDATE**

Try also changing this

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
```

To this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

In order to expose the __dirname for static files.

Comment: i have added 'cb(null, 'D:/project/uploads');' but still same

Comment: Do not use 'D:/project/uploads', use the __dirname global objects.
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname

Comment: same error, console.log(__dirname) results D:\project

Comment: The error must be somewhere with the express.static not able to host your folder for static files

Comment: Thank you so so much. saved me many hours of stress. adding next(null, path.join(__dirname, '.././public/uploads/images/')); worked

Answer (score 7):

So the answer is in the tutorials comments section on youtube. 
Instead of:

```
cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
```

do:

```
cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
```

Simple as.

Answer (score 6):

This what worked for me. I changed './uploads/' into '__dirname' so that it can find the correct directory/filename anywhere on your computer.

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, __dirname);
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
  }
});
```

Because when you set a specific folder name/directory you limit your image directory to be only or should be in that folder.

Comment: Thank you. It's Working.

Comment: Thank you.This worked for me, but I have no idea why I was getting such errors in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

I am doing the same course and I too had the same problem (i also use windows machine). The following worked for me:

```
const hash = require('random-hash'); // you have to install this package:

const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => { //this is storing the file in the images folder
        callback(null, path.join(__dirname, '/Images'));
    },

    filename: (req, file, callback) => { //this is just setting a unique filename
        let temp = file.originalname.split('.');
        const filename = temp[0] + '-' + hash.generateHash({length: 5}) + '.' + temp[1]
        callback(null, filename);
    }
});
```

This creates a unique hash for the filenames as well

Comment: You can also use node's built in crypto lib to generate the hash. So, you won't have to add another dependency. `crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex")` -> this bit will generate the hash

Answer (score 3):

I found this in the comments section, here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srPXMt1Q0nY&list=PL55RiY5tL51q4D-B63KBnygU6opNPFk_q&index=10

> OK guys, in case someone has an issue with this in the file creation
>   stage, that probably means you're working on Windows. Now, you don't
>   need to feel discouraged and throw your computer to the trash (I
>   actually like always having to find workarounds for my Windows :).
>
> There's at least a solution, and this is the one I found. My problem
>   is the file does not get created because Windows does not accept
>   filenames with colon (':') on it. My solution is rather simple. After
>   I get the current date, I use replace() and a regexp to change that
>   into a dash. Viola. It works!
>
> Just in case, this is one way to do it:
>       filename: function(req, file, cb){
>           const now = new Date().toISOString();
>           const date = now.replace(/:/g, '-');
>           cb(null, date + file.originalname); }

Hope it helps someone who´s working in windows.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same error while saving the file.
The path I provided in callback didn't exist already that's why I got that error

```
const fs = require('fs');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    fs.mkdir('./uploads/',(err)=>{
       cb(null, './uploads/');
    });
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
  }
});
```

With filesystem I created the same folder, In case of folder exists the **err** gets value but here nothing to worry about as we have that folder.
This worked for me. hope this would help

Comment: Yeah... it took me an hour to figure out that folder should be already there only then it saves the file.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error and this is how I resolved it. After using the replace method, I changed './uploads/images/' to 'uploads/images'. In this case, multer created the folder automatically. So you have something like this

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/');
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
     cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-')+ file.originalname);
      }
  });
```

For Windows users.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs because `./uploads/` does not exist.

**FYI :**
If you use multer like below

`const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads' })`

This creates uploads directories at server starting.

but if we use `destination` object then it does not create directory.

**Proof/ref:**  [image: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#diskstorage]
https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#diskstorage

**Solution**

```
const fs = require('fs'); // Added to create directories
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    // :::::::::::::::Create diretories:::::::::::::::::::
    fs.mkdir('./uploads/',(err)=>{
       cb(null, './uploads/');
    });
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
  }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  // reject a file
  if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
  },
  fileFilter: fileFilter
});
```

Answer (score 1):

every thing is fine. problem is on this line 
`cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);`
simply write `cb(null,file.originalname);` 
it will work. try to use in different way to add the date string with file name.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have permission to access /uploads/ on this server.

Try the following:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /uploads
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the file name. Because ':' is not allowed in Windows.

Eg:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null,'./uploads/');
    },
    filename: function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-') +'-'+ file.originalname);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you work with Windows OS, you should use another methods of `Date().i` write code like this:

```
filename:(req,file,cb)=>{ cb(null,new Date().toDateString()+file.originalname) }
```

Answer (score 1):

create folder **uploads** near app.js file

for this line

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
```

Answer (score 1):

use this  = > `cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);`  instead of   `cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);`  to prevent
`"error": "ENOENT: no such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

if this can't find a folder then you can create one

```
destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    fs.mkdir('./uploads/',(err)=>{
       cb(null, './uploads/');
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a limb here, many other people are very close and I'm sure that some of the answers work for some people, but nothing short of this answer I found [here](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/391#issuecomment-360731493) has worked for me (struggled with this for 2 weeks now).

```
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({

  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, path.resolve(__dirname, './test'))
  },

  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
  }
})
```

Comment: Worked for me! Important answer if all the others aren't working for you

Answer (score 1):

**What worked for me:(Windows OS)**

```
const path = require("path");
const multer = require("multer");

const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, path.join(__dirname, "Images")); 
//Images is folder which will hold uploaded images
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, "-") + file.originalname);
  },
});

app.use(multer({ storage: fileStorage }).single("image")); //Middleware
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note**:  In order to remove all special character, we can use replace function as

```
const cleanVariable = mixSpecialCharters.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    -cb(null, './uploads/');
    +cb(null, 'upload/');
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
  }
});
```

Comment: add more details

Answer (score 0):

in product.js just replace cb(null, new Date().toISOString()+ file.originalname)  with cb(null, Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname);

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
```

with

```
cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can avoid any directory issues

```js
const path = require("path");
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, path.join(__dirname, "../uploads"));
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
    cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + uniqueSuffix + file.originalname);
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req,file,cb){
        //if that dir is not created then this will create that dir first
        fs.mkdir('./uploads/',(err)=>{
            cb(null,'./uploads/');
        })
    },
    filename: function(req,file,cb)
    {
        cb(null,new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-') +'-'+file.originalname);
    }
})
```

this happens in windows and in mac due to ':' so just replace it

Answer (score 0):

As others suggest it is indeed an issue with how the OS is handeling parts of the date string, namely the ':'.
The purpose of this new Date().toISOString() is generating some randmoness, which can also be achieved with another 3rd party package like UUID for example:

```
filename: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, `${uuidv4()}-${file.originalname}`)
```

of course to use this library you have to install it and then refer it:

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid")
```

Answer (score 0):

`const path = require("path");

const multer = require("multer");

const dir = __dirname;

const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({

destination: function (req, file, cb) {

```
cb(null, path.extname(dir + "/public/my-uploads"));
```

},

filename: function (req, file, cb) {
cb(null, Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname);

},

});

module.exports = { fileStorage };
`
This Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, path.join(__dirname,'../uploads/');
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
  }
});
```

also for filename change new Date() into Date.now()

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the dist folder from `./uploads/` to `uploads/`

in this function

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads/');
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work, change this:

```
filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
  }
```

to

```
  filename:(req,file,cb)=>{
        const name = Date.now()+file.originalname;
        cb(null, name);
    }
```