# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, at Error (native)

Tags: node.js

This is error which am getting while post image, i have been searching answer for this type of errors but nothing works for me.
Am using "multer" to upload file

The folder 'uploads' available in the folder but it shows

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Nodejs\nodejs-wmc\uploads\04-10-2018-15:16:19*-2.jpg'
    at Error (native)`

**app.js**

```
var multer = require('multer');
var path = require('path');

 var storage = multer.diskStorage({

destination: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads')
},
filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    var id_photo = new Date();
    var dd = id_photo.getDate();
    var mm = id_photo.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = id_photo.getFullYear();
    var h = id_photo.getHours();
    var i = id_photo.getMinutes();
    var s = id_photo.getSeconds();
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }

    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm
    }

    if (h < 10) {
        h = '0' + h
    }

    if (i < 10) {
        i = '0' + i
    }

    if (s < 10) {
        s = '0' + s
    }
    id_photo = mm + '-' + dd + '-' + yyyy + '-' + h + ':' + i + ':' + s;
    callback(null, id_photo + "*-" + file.originalname);
}
})

var upload = multer({
storage: storage,
}).any();

app.use(upload);
```

**galery.js**

```
this.submitInsertGalery = function(req, res) {
    if (req.fileValidationError) {
      res.send(req.fileValidationError);
      return;
    }

    res.send(req.files);
    return;

    if(req.files.length == 0){
      res.send("Image Can't Empty ");
      return;
    }

    var photo = req.files[0].filename;
    var url = '/files/' + photo;

    var id = uuidv1();
    var motor_type = req.body.motor_type;
    var price = req.body.price;
    var description = req.body.description;
    var spesifikasi = req.body.spesifikasi;
    var created_at = new Date();
    var modified_at = new Date();
    var created_by = "ratri";
    var modi_by = "ratri";

    connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
      con.query('INSERT INTO galerys (id, motor_type, price, description, spesifikasi, image1, created_at, modified_at, created_by, modi_by) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', 
        [id, motor_type, price, description, spesifikasi, photo, created_at, modified_at, created_by, modi_by], function(err, result){
            con.release();
            if (err) {
                res.send({ status: 400, message: 'Master galery creation failed' });
            } else {
                res.redirect('/UploadGalery/Index?toast=' + 'add');
            }
      });
    });
  };
```

my html

```
<form action="/UploadGalery/AddSubmit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left" novalidate>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-6 col-xs-11"> 
   <input type="file" name="file">    
</div>
</form>
```

i also have tried this [ENOENT: no such file or directory .?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48418680/enoent-no-such-file-or-directory) but didnt work..

can anyone help me? thank you..

Comment: Are you sure you have a file with an asterisk in its filename or are you trying to get them through a regular expression?

Comment: I am trying to save an image whose image name contains an asterisk