# I get a 'Render Error: Cannot read property 'isLoggedIn' of undefined' while trying to connect react frontend to Django backend

Tags: django, react-native, expo, render, callstack

I'm working with react native as front end and django as backend to create an app using expo. i'm using expo go which means i'm creating it directly on my mobile phone.

the issue is my front end cannot read my backend api

i get a render error that says: cannot read property 'isLoggedIn' of undefined.

i've been stuck on this for 3 days i don't know what to do.

i will appreciate every suggestions.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, createContext } from "react";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

import Navigator from "../navigation/navigator";



const Context = createContext()

const Provider = () => {


    const [ domain, setDomain] = useState("http://192.168.27.95:8000")
    const [ isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn ] = useState(false)
    const [ appSettings, setAppSettings ] = useState({})

    function initAppSettings() {
        fetch(`${domain}/api/v1.0/app/settings`, {
            method: 'GET'
        })
        .then(res => {
            if (res.ok){
                return res.json()
            } else {
                throw res.json()
            }
        })
        .then(json => {
            setAppSettings(json)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        initAppSettings()
    }, [])


    const globalContext = {
        domain,
        isLoggedIn, 
        setIsLoggedIn,
        appSettings,
        setAppSettings,
    }

    return <Context.Provider value={globalContext}><SafeAreaProvider><Navigator /></SafeAreaProvider></Context.Provider>

};

export { Context, Provider };
```

```
'userAPI.apps.UserapiConfig',
'appSettings.apps.AppsettingsConfig',

'rest_framework',
'rest_framework_simplejwt',
'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
"corsheaders",
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read property 'isLoggedIn' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55205465/cannot-read-property-isloggedin-of-undefined)